# new affectiva SDK ver 3.1.2 using difficulty

Tags: java, android, affdex-sdk

I was using affectiva trial version, but after the expiration of my licence, I have no choice except updating my codes to adapt with latest free version. although after doing what this page sais all errors disappears, I have an error while running time.
the word is, I cant handle [this](http://developer.affectiva.com/v3_1_2/android/) because I think it's related to the SDK

here is my stack trace:

> 10-08 18:02:02.291 27539-27539/org.telegram.messenger.beta I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
>   10-08 18:02:02.292 27539-27539/org.telegram.messenger.beta I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
>   10-08 18:02:02.380 2218-2218/org.telegram.messenger.beta:remote I/EMOSERV: Service onCreate
>   10-08 18:02:02.391 2218-2218/org.telegram.messenger.beta:remote I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
>   10-08 18:02:02.574 2218-2218/org.telegram.messenger.beta:remote I/EMOSERV: initializeCameraDetector completed 
>   10-08 18:02:02.907 2218-2218/org.telegram.messenger.beta:remote E/AffdexFace_native: Wrong operator name: MinOpWithThreshold
>   10-08 18:02:05.369 2301-2301/org.telegram.messenger.beta:remote I/EMOSERV: Service onCreate
>   10-08 18:02:05.381 2301-2301/org.telegram.messenger.beta:remote I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
>   10-08 18:02:05.548 2301-2301/org.telegram.messenger.beta:remote I/EMOSERV: initializeCameraDetector completed 
>   10-08 18:02:05.875 2301-2301/org.telegram.messenger.beta:remote E/AffdexFace_native: Wrong operator name: MinOpWithThreshold
>   10-08 18:13:47.808 27539-27595/org.telegram.messenger.beta E/ContentResolver: Unknown URI content://com.teslacoilsw.notifier/unread_count
>   10-08 18:13:47.812 27539-27539/org.telegram.messenger.beta I/SendBroadcastPermission: action:android.intent.action.BADGE_COUNT_UPDATE, mPermissionType:0
>   10-08 18:17:50.958 27539-27595/org.telegram.messenger.beta E/ContentResolver: Unknown URI content://com.teslacoilsw.notifier/unread_count
>   10-08 18:17:50.969 27539-27539/org.telegram.messenger.beta I/SendBroadcastPermission: action:android.intent.action.BADGE_COUNT_UPDATE, mPermissionType:0

Answer (score 1):

From the logs, it looks like you need to delete the old SDK from your project. Make sure to delete the libaffdexface_jni.so and the affdex jars library in your lib folder, if they exist. The new libraries should be loaded automatically from our maven repository when u add affdex-sdk definition to your app build.gradle.